# Can I tune a banjolel to DGBE?

Tags: alternative-tunings

I play baritone uke tuned DGBE.  Can I set up my banjolele to be DGBE also?  Banjolele now is standard uke GCEA tuning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the tuning of your banjolele.  The problem is that you can't just tune your current strings up or down to the new tuning.  The thickness of the strings have to be such that they provide the correct tension for the notes that you want to voice.

D'Addario provides a primer on [string tension](http://www.daddario.com/DAstringtensionguide.Page). Unfortunately they don't have tension measurements for Ukulele strings in their PDF.

They also have a string tension web program to figure out what string gauges you need:  http://stringtensionpro.com/

You'll have to decide if you are using plain nylon or wound strings, and which octave you want the notes to be in.

EDIT: I ran the numbers for a similar question, posting them here also:

I ran the maths on the string tensions for a tuning of DGBE at the 4th octave for the DGB and 5th for the E on a standard soprano Ukulele scale length.  The Ukulele tension of the strings has a range from low tension to a higher tension:
(in Kg, 1st string is highest)

- 1st string: 3.5 - 5.5 kg
- 2nd string: 3.2 - 5.3
- 3rd string: 3.1 - 5.6
- 4ths string 3.4 - 6.7

This puts the gauges available (in 100's of an inch):

- E (1st) .014 - .018
- B (2nd) .018 - .023
- G (3rd) .023 - .029
- D (4th) .031 - .040

Both D'Addario and Savarez sell nylon string singles in various gauges, so you should be able to find strings in each range. You'll probably have to experiment to find what tensions you prefer.